# Python lxml xpath XPathEvalError: Invalid expression -- why?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I'm trying to parse an SVG document with `lxml`.  Here's my code:

```py
nsmap = {
    'svg': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
    'xlink': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
}

root = etree.XML(svg)

# this works (finds the element with the given ID)
root.xpath('./svg:g/svg:g/svg:g[@id="route_1_edge"]', namespaces=nsmap)

# this yields "XPathEvalError: Invalid expression"
root.xpath('./svg:g/svg:g/svg:g[fn:startswith(@id,"route_1")]', namespaces=nsmap)
```

Anyone know why the first one works and the second doesn't?  If I change the third `svg:g` to `svg:text` I don't get an exception, so it seems to be something to do with the `g` element in particular that it doesn't like, though, again, the simple `g[@id="foo"]` search works fine.

Comment: Hey thanks for this.  The question answered my problem :)

Comment: I think the reason I haven't had to understand this is the same reason an external CSS selector library for lxml is available http://lxml.de/cssselect.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "startswith" function is spelled [starts-with](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with). Also, omit the `fn:`.

```
root.xpath('./svg:g/svg:g/svg:g[starts-with(@id,"route_1")]', namespaces=nsmap)
```

---

```
import lxml.etree as etree
import lxml.builder as builder

nsmap = {
    'svg': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
    'xlink': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink',
}

E = builder.ElementMaker(
    namespace='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
    nsmap=nsmap)

root = (
    E.root(
        E.g(
            E.g(
                E.g(id = "route_1_edge" )))))

print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
print(root.xpath('./svg:g/svg:g/svg:g[@id="route_1_edge"]', namespaces=nsmap))
print(root.xpath('./svg:g/svg:g/svg:g[starts-with(@id,"route_1")]', namespaces=nsmap))
```

yields

```
<svg:root xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <svg:g>
    <svg:g>
      <svg:g id="route_1_edge"/>
    </svg:g>
  </svg:g>
</svg:root>

[<Element {http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}g at 0xb7462c34>]
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}g at 0xb7462be4>]
```

Comment: That works (though you typoed starts-with in your answer.  I got "fn:startswith" from this answer to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2359880/340404 -- I guess there's an error in that answer.